# Sub divide a pie section Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is it possible to further divide a pie section?

I have data to show on the pie chart:

```
['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
['Work',     11],
['Eat',       2],
['Sleep',     7],
['Other',     4]
```

If I want to subdivide the 'Other' section of pie chart into:

```
['Commute',  2],
['Watch TV', 2]
```

Is that possible?

**EDIT:**

```
 function drawChart() { var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ ['Task', 'Hours per Day'], ['Work', 11], ['Eat', 2], ['Other', 4], ['Sleep', 7] ]); var options = { title: 'My Daily Activities' }; var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart')); chart.draw(data, options); }
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? please show some code. Thanks!

Comment: I have just created a basic pie chart. I can't think of a way to further divide the section

Comment: it's not possible out of the box. you could try manually changing the svg on the chart's `'ready'` event...

Comment: @WhiteHat thank you for your valuable comment. I will try to change it at 'ready' event.